# LibreOffice Base and unmet dependencies

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, libreoffice, dpkg

My database in LibreOffice Base is all of a sudden locked for editing. Moreover, LibreOffice Base exits whenever I try to insert a photo into a database post. I have worked in my relational database for months and have not made any changes to the design, only populated it.

I have tried to remove LibreOffice Base in order to be able to install the software afresh. This is not possible through the Software Center. Here is the error message:

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: error processing libx11-6 (--configure):
 libx11-6:amd64 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.1 cannot be configured because libx11-6:i386 is in a different version (2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2)
dpkg: error processing libx11-6:i386 (--configure):
 libx11-6:i386 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2 cannot be configured because libx11-6:amd64 is in a different version (2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libx11-6
 libx11-6:i386
Error in function: 
dpkg: error processing libx11-6 (--configure):
 libx11-6:amd64 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.1 cannot be configured because libx11-6:i386 is in a different version (2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2)
dpkg: error processing libx11-6:i386 (--configure):
 libx11-6:i386 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2 cannot be configured because libx11-6:amd64 is in a different version (2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.1)
```

The Software Center asks if I want to try to repair the error or cancel. Choosing repair results in the same menu popping up again and again and again to ask if I want to repair the error or cancel.

I have run `apt-get install -f` more times than I care to remember. The result is this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic libraw5 linux-headers-2.6.38-8 libplot2c2 libpano13-bin libqjson0 libpano13-2 libzthread-2.3-2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libx11-6
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libx11-6
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 63 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/763 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: error processing libx11-6 (--configure):
 libx11-6:amd64 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.1 cannot be configured because libx11-6:i386 is in a different version (2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2)
dpkg: error processing libx11-6:i386 (--configure):
 libx11-6:i386 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.2 cannot be configured because libx11-6:amd64 is in a different version (2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2.1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libx11-6
 libx11-6:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried `apt-get update`, `apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get autoclean`, all of them to no avail.

The problem seems to my novice eyes to be to do with libx11-6 where some file is in a wrong version, and it is clear that `apt-get install -f` does not solve the problem. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have conflicting versions of libx11-6 installed. When they fail to agree, it stops the whole install process. What you need to do isone of the following:

remove the i386 version of libx11-6 (`apt-get remove libx11-6:i386`). This might not be an option if a 32-bit application depends on it.

upgrade the amd64 version of libx11-6 (`apt-get upgrade libx11-6`). This might not be an option if there is no upgrade available.

downgrade the i386 version of libx11-6 (I've never done this without Synaptic). This is a last resort.

Once you have done one of the above, the install should proceed normally. This might have also been causing your LibreOffice problem, but I don't know.